# SharePoint: Calendar List, multiple overlays - not visible in All/Current Events view

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a calendar list in a SharePoint 2010 enterprise site which uses a few other calendars as overlays. When I view it in Calendar View all is fine - the events from the other calendars are showing up as expected. However, when I change to All or Current Events view, these events don't show up. Is there any way of showing aggregated events from other calendars in a All/Current Events view? It seems like such an obvious feature, but I can't find it...

C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calendar overlays work per view - so if you create a view and apply overlays to it, those same overlays don't apply to other views.